# Using java Collection<E>.contains(Object o) when overriding equals method

Tags: java, list

I have a List<Person> objects where person is defined like so

```
public Person {
    private firstName;
    private lastName;
    //getter and setter methods
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return lastName.equals(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

Now I want to see if this List<Person> contains a certain last name.

```
if(myList.contains("Smith"))
    System.out.println("yay!");
```

However the way the contains method is specified is that is returns true when (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)). So in this instance it is using String.equals(Person) instead of Person.equals(String). Is there a simple way of fixing this or do I have to write my own logic for contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Is there a simple way of fixing this...***

No, not using `Collection.contains`.

By the contract of [`equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) the implementation must be *symmetric*:

> *for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.*

This means that returning any thing else than `false` for `somePerson.equals(someString)` is a direct violation of the contract.

> ***...or do I have to write my own logic for contains?***

Yes. Use a for loop:

```
for (Person p : myList)
    if (p.getLastName().equals("Smith"))
        return true;
return false;
```

or, if you're using Java 8,

```
return myList.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.getLastName().equals("Smith"));
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to construct a `List<String>` view using the existing myList and go ahead.

```
final List<Person> myList = yourList;
List<String> strView = new AbstractList<String>() { 
                    String get(int i) {
                             return myList.get(i).getLastName(); 
                       } 
                     int size() { return myList.size(); }
                  };

if(strView.contains("Smith")) System.out.println("Yaay");
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write your own logic for this.

I would strongly advise that when you override the equals method, you stick to the API defined by java Object#equals.  The equals method is used in many places (hashmaps to name one), and using a different logic will get you into lots of trouble later on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not looking for a `Person` the most communicative solution would be to have a method that specifically indicates it's looking for a last name, like `containsLastName` or whatever, or take an example `Person` and use it as a criteria-like object.

Answer (score 0):

Another option here is to use Guava's [Iterables.any](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#any%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29)

```
 Predicate<Person> findMe(final String name){
    return new Predicate<Person>(){
        public boolean apply(Person input){
            return input.lastname.equals(name);
        }
    }
 }

 boolean contains = Iterables.any(myList, findMe("Smith"));
```

Or

```
Function<Person, String> lastName = new Function<Person, String>(){
     public String apply(Person input){
        return input.lastName;
     }
}

boolean contains = Lists.transform(myList, lastName).contains("Smith");
```